# how can i apply functions in preexisting matrix and create new vector in R

Tags: r

i have a file that looks like

> A     B
>
> 1     0.5  0.7
>
> 2     0.6  0.2
>
> 3     1.5  3.0
>
> ...
>
> 200  0.9  1.1

what i want to do is to start with 200 and equally devide 200 into 100 and 100 and multiply to each A1(0.5) and B1(0.7) resulting in 50 and 70

And then i want to sum those two result(120), divide it in half(60 and 60)  and repeat the process to A2(0.6), B2(0.2) resulting in 36 and 35,(sum of them are 71) untill A200 and B200.

I want to create a new vector with these sums (120, 71,.... etc)

How can i create this vector with functions in R??

Comment: It is not clear what you want.  BTW, how is that 0.5 changing to 45?

Comment: @akrun  thanks for pointing out my mistakes... must have confused with other datas..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to create a data frame where you stock those data, then if i got your point this should work

```
n=200
for( i in 1:200) {
coef=coef/2
sum=(data[i,1]+data[i,2])*coef
vect=c(vect,sum)

}
```

vect stocks all the sums.